# Subclassing django's fileField form's widget?

Tags: python, django

I have uploading working just fine, but the problem is, I would like to filter out all file types that are not needed.
I know with html, you can use something like:

`<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*" id="file"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Image!">`

and in this case, this tells the browser to only show image files in the file dialog box.

I can't figure out how I can add the accept="image/*" to Django's widget.

Any help is most welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change this with the widget `attrs` as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):    
    my_file = forms.FileField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_file'].widget.attrs.update({'accept': 'image/*'})
```

Or you can use something like [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/kmike/django-widget-tweaks) to do this with a templatetag.

Comment: `self.fields['my_file'].widget.attrs=({'accept': 'image/*'})` works, thanks again!